# Travelling by bus

Tags: algorithm

> If you have the full bus schedule for a country, how can you find the
>   furthest anyone can travel in one day without visiting the same stop twice?

I assume a bus schedule gives you the full list of leaving and arriving times for every bus stop.

A slow and naive method would be as follows.

You can of course make a graph from the bus schedule with multiple directed edges between bus stops. You could then do a depth first search remembering the arrival time of the edge you took to get to each node and only taking edges from that stop that leave after the one that you took to get there. If you go to a node you have been to before you would only carry on from there if the current time in your traversal is before the earliest time you had ever visited that node before. You could record the furthest you can get from each node and then you could check each node to find the furthest you can travel overall.

This seems very inefficient however and it really isn't a normal graph problem. The problem is that in a normal directed graph if you can get from A to B and from B to C then you can get from A to C. This isn't true here.

What is the fastest you can solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your original algorithm is pretty good.

You can think of your approach as being a version of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), in attempting to find the shortest path to each node.

Note that it is best at this stage to weight edges in the graph in terms of time.  The idea is to use your Dijkstra-like algorithm to compute all nodes reachable within 1 days worth of time, and then pick whichever of these nodes is furthest in space from the start point.

Implementations of Dijkstra can use a heap to retrieve the next node to explore in O(logn), and I think this would be a good enhancement to your approach as well.  If you always choose the node that you can reach earliest, you never need to repeat the calculation for that node.

Overall the approach is:

1. For each starting point
2. Use a modified Dijkstra to compute all nodes reachable in 1 day
3. Find the furthest in space of all these nodes.

So for n starting points and e bus routes, the complexity is about O(n(n+e)log(n)) to get the optimal answer.

You should be able to get improved performance by using an appropriate heuristic in an [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm).  The heuristic needs to underestimate the max distance possible from a point, so you could use the maximum speed of a bus multiplied by the remaining time.

Comment: How are you defining a bus route for the value e?

Comment: If there is a way of going from A to the next stop of B on a bus, then that counts as 1 edge.

Comment: Complexity makes me shudder a little, but this is a rigorous solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making multiple edges for each departure from a location, you can make multiple nodes per location / time.

1. Create one node per location per departure time.
2. Create one node per location per arrival time.
3. Create edges to connect departures to arrivals.
4. Create edges to connect a given node to the node belonging to the same location at the nearest future time.

By doing this, any path you can traverse through the graph is "valid"  (meaning a traveler would be able to achieve this by a combination of bus trips or choosing to sit at a location and wait for a future bus).

Comment: +1 seems identical model to mine (and of course independently arrived)

Comment: @randomstring - Yes, it appears so!  Except you go one step further and suggest a linear time solution, while I leave it up to the imagination to find the weightiest path.

Answer (score 3):

The simplistic graph representation will not work. I. e. each city is a node and the edges represent time. That's because the "edge" is not always active -- it is only active at certain times of the day.

The second thing that comes to mind is Edward Tufte's Paris Train Schedule [image: Paris Train Schedule] which is a different kind of graph. But that does not quite fit the problem either. With the train schedule, the stations have a sequential relationship between stations, but that's not the case in general with cities and bus schedules.

But Tufte motivates the following way to model it as a graph. You could write code only to construct the graph and use a standard graph library that includes the shortest path algorithm.

- Each bus trip is an edge with weight = distance covered
- Each (city, departure) and (city, arrival) is a node
- All nodes for a given city are connected by zero-weight edges in a time-ordered sequence, ignoring whether it is an arrival or a departure. This subgraph will look like a chain.
- (it is a directed graph)

**Linear Time Solution:** Note that the graph will be a directed, acyclic graph. Finding the longest path in such a graph is [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). *"A longest path between two given vertices s and t in a weighted graph G is the same thing as a shortest path in a graph −G derived from G by changing every weight to its negation. Therefore, if shortest paths can be found in −G, then longest paths can also be found in G."*

Hope this helps! If somebody can post a visualization of the graph, it would be nice. If I can do so myself, I will do 1 more edit.

Comment: @felix Because this is not an answer, perhaps?

Comment: placeholder, such interesting questions are closed very aggressively. if not closed, i will post a fuller answer.

Comment: @randomstring - not the downvoter(s), but per Meta, [do not answer with placeholder answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166663/how-do-we-feel-about-placeholder-answers-to-indicate-we-are-working-on-an-answer)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks. My intent is different. I am not editing to bump it up. Anyways, I do not do this often. I will do just 1 more edit for completion. Thanks for reverting the downvotes, folks!

Comment: Placeholders are potentially expensive - best not to post an answer unless it's an answer. In the future, post a summary of what you are thinking of (perhaps with a "more to come..." as a comment)

Comment: @randomstring Thanks also for not giving up!

Comment: @randomstring - Sure... and remember, you can't control how people will vote. Nothing on SO is immune from a downvote, so supreme quality (and a degree of detachment) is of the utmost importance.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 paradoxically, I earned 22 rep already even before completing the answer! But I do appreciate the constructive suggestions and I will use comments to indicate the intention the next time. The last time even before I could write a 2 sentence summary with more to come, the question was closed. The real issue is the extremely aggressive closing going around. I am heartened that there are some folks who upvoted this to make it worth the effort! I wish SO would not forget that at the end of the day, it is algorithms and computer science that are the most important parts of tech.

Comment: +1: this problem reminded me of Tufte's books and this graph in particular also!

Comment: Your linear-time solution is neither linear-time nor a solution, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @tmyklebu thanks, i will think it over. for now, i'm done with this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but as described this problem has a pretty high complexity. Misread the problem originally and thought it was np-hard, but it is not. It does however have a pretty high complexity that I personally would not want to deal with. This algorithm is a pretty good approximation that give a considerable complexity savings that I personally think it worth it.

However, if all you want is an answer that is "pretty good" there are are lot of fairly efficient algorithms out there that will get close very quickly.

Personally I would suggest using a simple greedy algorithm here.

I've done this on a few (granted, small and contrived) examples and it's worked pretty well and has an `nlog(n)` efficiency.

- Associate a `velocity` with each node, velocity being the fastest you can move away from a given node. In my examples this velocity was `distance_travelled/(wait_time + travel_time)`. I used the maximum velocity of all trips leaving a node as the velocity score for that node.
- From your node/time calculate the velocities of all neighboring nodes and travel to the "fastest" node.

This algorithm is pretty good for the complexity as it basically transforms the problem into a static search, but there are a couple potential pitfalls that could be adjusted for depending on your data set.

The biggest issue with this algorithm is the possibility of a really fast bus going into the middle of nowhere. You could get around that by adding a "popularity" term to the velocity calculation (make more popular stops effectively faster) but depending on your data set that could easily make things either better or worse.

Comment: Pretty good is OK with me and also something with good parameterized complexity would be attractive.  Is it NP-Hard because you could in theory set the bus schedules to impose no constraints at all and then you end up with the longest path problem?  What greedy algorithm do you suggest?

Comment: It's definitely not NP-hard.  There are linearly many relevant starting times and linearly many starting locations.  Run Dijkstra's algorithm form each one and you can find the earliest time you can reach each stop of each bus.

Comment: @tmyklebu ah whoops, totally misread the problem. Thought it was in arbitrary time length, you're right, not np hard.

Comment: Yes, of course it's a different problem.  It's a subproblem.  You solve this problem by taking a max over all sources, destinations, and starting times of the answer to that subproblem.  If you can reduce a problem to polynomially many instances of an easy problem, either your problem isn't NP-hard or you're going to make a million dollars.

Comment: @tmyklebu I'm inclined to believe that a million dollars is a huge understatement.

Answer (score -1):

Naive is the best you'll get -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

EDIT:

So the problem is two fold.

1. Create a list of graphs where its possible to travel from pointA to pointB. Possible is in terms of times available for busA to travel from pointA to pointB.
2. Find longest path from all the possible generated path above.

Another approach would be to reevaluate the graph upon each node traversal and find the longest path. 
It still reduces to finding longest possible path, which is NP-Hard.

Comment: the thing is it's not a graph because of the time schedule constraint

Comment: This should be a comment. [*Barely more than a link to an external site*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: weighted graph? where the weight represents the time it takes from nodeA to nodeB

Comment: The problem is that in a normal directed graph if you can get from A to B and from B to C then you can get from A to C. This isn't true here.

Comment: @felix why not? To get from A->C, you would have to utlize B. Similary to get from townA to townC, you have to pass by townB?

Comment: Imagine you can get a bus at 2pm from A to B and a bus at 9am from B to C. You can't get from A to C before midnight, as an example, as you arrive too late.